# How do I reference a cell string to use as a note in another cell?

Tags: google-sheets

I'm simply looking for how to link one cell's data into another cell as a note<sup>1</sup>.

What I have here simply errors telling me I do not have permission to setNote. :/

```
function noteSetter() {
 var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
 var sheet = ss.getSheets()[0];

 var cell = sheet.getRange("B2");
 cell.setNote("This is a note");
}
```

---

<sup>1</sup>: Open a Google spreadsheet->Rightclick a cell->Insert Note. I want data from, say A1 a string "Moo", to link into another cell, B1, so B1 has a note attached to it with the content of cell A1 "Moo". When you then hover your cursor over B1, the note pops up with "Moo".

Comment: How do you mean "as a note"?

Comment: Open a Google spreadsheet->Rightclick a cell->Insert Note.

I don't think I can make this more clear. I want data from, say A1 a string "Moo", to link into another cell, B1, so B1 has a note attached to it with the content of cell A1 "Moo". When you then hover your cursor over B1, the note pops up with "Moo".

Comment: What is the exact error message you get?

Comment: @Paul: Comments are temporary. You should [edit] your post to include that information in your question.

Answer (score 1):

I can't manage to get by the permission error, this might work for you.

```
function onEdit(e) {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  if (sheet.getName() == "Project"){ //Change to your sheet name
    var sourceRange = e.source.getActiveRange();
    var sourceRow = sourceRange.getRow();
    var sourceColumn = sourceRange.getColumn();
    var sourceValue = sourceRange.getValue();

    if(sourceColumn == 1){ //Change to the column you want to get the value from
      var noteCell = sheet.getRange(sourceRow, 2); //The cell where the Note should be, B-column on the current row
      noteCell.setNote(sourceValue);
    }
  }
}
```

**EDIT**
I do believe this is what you want. The function above sets a note on the cell in the B-column on the current row, if the cell in the A-column is edited.

If you don't want the note to update with `A1` you should be able to use the function you wrote, with a slight modification to get the value from `A1`.

```
function noteSetter() {
 var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
 var sheet = ss.getSheets()[0];

 var cell = sheet.getRange(2, 2);
 cell.setNote(sheet.getRange(1,1).getValue());
}

function onOpen() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var entries = [{
  name : "Set cell note",
    functionName : "noteSetter"
  }];
  sheet.addMenu("Scripts", entries);
};
```

I added a function to add the script to a Custom menu, to make it easier to access, if you don't want that you can just remove the `onOpen`-function.

Comment: Ill edit my post to reflect what I have currently. Im not trying to  use a formula in a note, im trying to use a formula inside a cell that can set its own note as another cells string value. However setComment (nor setNote, the are different things) doesn't seem to work in anything except the OnEdit function.

Comment: This goes back to my original question; how can I do this in a cell formula? When I try I simply get the error above "You do not have permission to call setNote"

Comment: Your code works for me. But when you say that you do this in a cell formula, do you mean that you write the code in the cell itself?

Comment: Yes its in the cell itself as I need it to have a relative affect on other cells.

Comment: How do you write script in a cell? I've never done that.

Comment: Well a function from a script is what I mean.

     `function Lol(number) {
       var x = 10*number
       return x;
     }`

So I slap `=Lol(C3)` where C3 has a value of 1 and the new cell has a value of 10.

Comment: Okay, now I get you. But why do you want to run the function from a cell? Why not just use `onEdit`?

Comment: I need it to have a relative affect on other cells.
"How do I reference a cell string to use as a note in another cell?"

Comment: Check my edited answer. Wouldn't that solve your problem? Otherwise it would be useful to see an example spreadsheet with what you want to achieve.

Comment: Nice answer on it: function onEdit(e) { var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet(); if (sheet.getName() == "Project"){ //Change to your sheet name var sourceRange = e.source.getActiveRange(); var sourceRow = sourceRange.getRow(); var sourceColumn = sourceRange.getColumn(); var sourceValue = sourceRange.getValue(); if(sourceColumn == 1){ //Change to the column you want to get the value from var noteCell = sheet.getRange(sourceRow, 2); //The cell where the Note should be, B-column on the current row noteCell.setNote(sourceValue); } } } This is work like a charm for me. But, the another issue ap

Comment: But, the another issue appears. Let's say that in Column 1 we are using Formula to write the data from another sheet. When any changes occur to the formula result, it will be displayed in Column 1. But, since there's no Edit occur in Column 1, nothing will be put in Column 2's comment. Do any one have solution for it? Is there any function that available to see the changes of the formula result (instead of direct edit on that cell)? Or, should we implement changes per second (roughly execution)? Thanks for the attention for this issue.