# Insert cell's note from a relevance cell of another sheet

Tags: google-sheets

I am making a few of matrix of educational programs.

I need to insert cell's note (for example in sheet D1) from a cell of another sheet (for example sheet "dict_LO") by key cells of both sheets with some word (this word is in the cell where to insert note).

On [a post](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/57309/how-do-i-reference-a-cell-string-to-use-as-a-note-in-another-cell/99444#99444) is a solution.
[Punchlinern](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/users/29712/punchlinern) proposed a script:

```
function noteSetter() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheets()[0];

  var cell = sheet.getRange(2, 2);
  cell.setNote(sheet.getRange(1,1).getValue());
}

function onOpen() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var entries = [{
  name : "Set cell note",
    functionName : "noteSetter"
  }];
  sheet.addMenu("Scripts", entries);
};
```

This script must be modified under my conditions, but I do not know how :(

How does it?

Voila, [my spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1s5uw8hcddykzWfivJ6L-hpx4c62fiRL88M86-0atbAg/edit#gid=811667387).

Comment: Please **do not** use URL shorteners here.

Comment: I'm sorry. This is full URL [link] (https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1s5uw8hcddykzWfivJ6L-hpx4c62fiRL88M86-0atbAg/edit#gid=97863505)

Comment: Comments are meant to be temporary. You'd want to [edit] your question, but I've already done that.

Answer (score -1):

The following code looks for the selected value on the first column of simple table of notes. If the value is found the add a note with the corresponding description, otherwise add a note with an error message.

```
function noteSetter() {
  // Customize this values according to your needs.
  var notesSheetName = 'Notes';
  var notesColumn = 2;

  // Intialize variables with relevant Spreasheet objects
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var notesSheet = ss.getSheetByName(notesSheetName);
  var notesMatrix = notesSheet
        .getRange(1,1,notesSheet.getLastRow(),1)
        .getValues();
  // Convert a 1xn matrix (2D array) to a list of values (1D array)      
  var notesList = notesMatrix.join(',').split(',');
  // Get the key to look for on the notes sheet
  var range = ss.getActiveRange();
  var key = range.getValue();
  // Find the row number of the required note
  var notesRow = notesList.indexOf(key)+1;

  // Set note
  // If the key is found, then set the corresponding note,
  // otherwise then set an error message.
  var note = '';
  if(notesRow >=1) {
    note = notesSheet.getRange(notesRow,notesColumn).getValue();
  } else {
    note = 'Key not found';
  }
  range.setNote(note);
}
```